# Can I implement Singleton pattern partially?

Tags: python, class

I want to get one instance if identical arguments are passed. And different - if at least one argument is different

```
instance1 = someClass(arg1, arg2, arg3)
instance2 = someClass(arg1, arg4, arg5)
instance3 = someClass(arg1, arg2, arg3)
print(id(instance1) == id(instance2))  # should print False
print(id(instance1) == id(instance3))  # should print True
```

I think this can be implemented using two classes, one of which will create a new instance of the second, or return an existing one. But maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: That is not a singleton, that is really just a cache.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of singleton you can use `functools.lru_cache` as suggested by @luk2305 in comments

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
class someClass:
  def __init__(self, a, b, c):
    pass

a = someClass(2,3,4)
print(a) # different id
b = someClass(2,3,5)
print(b) # different id
c = someClass(2,3,4)
print(c) # same id as a
```